# inheritance from generic interface with type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

The code says it all:

```
interface a { }
interface ab : a { }
interface ac : a { }
interface igeneric<T> { }

//this is OK
class Clazz : igeneric<ab>, igeneric<ac>
{
}

//compiler error : 'Clazz2<T>' cannot implement both '<ac>' and 'igeneric<T>' because they may unify for some type parameter substitutions
class Clazz2<T> : igeneric<T>, igeneric<ac> where T : ab
{ 
}
```

Any ideas? Workarounds?

Comment: The inheritance hierarchy has no bearing on this: remove `a` entirely and note you get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a few ideas:

- You certainly cannot do what you are trying to do. Compiler has made it clear
- You certainly should not need to do what you are trying to do. `Generic` is a `type-less` inheritance of behaviour. Implementing 2 `type-full` generic interfaces of the same kind **does not make any sense**.
- You have not presented the original problem you are trying to solve. If you do, we might be able to help you with the design.

---

## UPDATE

> They are not of the same kind, one is
>   g and the other is g. think
>   about IMessageHandler and
>   IMessageHandler, in a class
>   implementing both Handle(MessageA) and
>   Handle(MessageB)

In the real world, you would not do that. Also it can lead to numerous problems. Let's say we have:

```
interface IFactory<T>
{
   T Create();
}
```

Then if I implement two:

```
class DontDoIt : IFactory<A>, IFactory<B>
{
    A Create();
    B Create(); // won't compile
}
```

This will not compile since the methods are different only in return type. Now you can perhaps overcome it by implementing the interfaces explicitly, but as I said *it just does not make sense from the design principles*.

Comment: They are not of the same kind, one is g<ab> and the other is g<ac>. think about IMessageHandler<MessageA> and IMessageHandler<MessageB>, in a class implementing both Handle(MessageA) and Handle(MessageB)